# Context is 'undefined' in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

using useContext hook, I tried to drill down a state variable as below

---

file : sharedContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const SharedStateContext = createContext();
```

file : template.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Layout, Menu } from "antd";
import { SharedStateContext } from "./sharedContext";
const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

const Template = ({ children, selectedKeys }) => {
  const [sharedState, setSharedState] = useState({ message: "hello", user : "foo" });

  return (
    <Layout style={styles.layout}>
      // context provider
      <SharedStateContext.Provider value={sharedState}>
        <Header style={styles.header}>
          <div className="demo-logo" />
          <Menu
            theme="dark"
            mode="horizontal"
            selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
            items={navItems}
          />
        </Header>
        <Content style={styles.content}>{children}</Content>
        <Footer style={styles.footer}>footer</Footer>
      </SharedStateContext.Provider>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

file : page.js

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { SharedStateContext } from "@/template/sharedContext";
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";

const HomePage = () => {

  const sharedState = useContext(SharedStateContext);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sharedState);
  },[]}

  // rest of the code

}
```

the log results 'sharedState',

> undefined

I tried setting the **layout.js** as a client component ('use client'), but still no good!